# RabbitMQ: Route based on Header + Routing Key

Tags: rabbitmq

Is there a way to bind a queue to an exchange by the combination of Routing Key plus Header Value(s)?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Could you explain better what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to mix routing logic, at least with one exchange (see explanation and workaround below).

Each exchange type has it own routing mechanism, `headers` and `topic` exchanges (as well as others) logic can't be mixed.

If you really sure you need at the same time routing key and headers routing, you can try to play with [Exchange to Exchange binding](https://www.rabbitmq.com/e2e.html) (here is good explanation how it works: [Exchange to Exchange bindings in RabbitMQ blog](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/10/19/exchange-to-exchange-bindings/)).

P.S.: But it would be better if you explain what problem you are trying to solve, while it looks like you really complicate things (behavior you've asked about is not very common).

Comment: I thought about that too, to bind a Topic into a Header exchange and to combine both. I am developing a micro services architecture, and i was thinking to be able to catch a message sent to a routing key as OPERATION.SAVE having content-type header or property value JSON, and then pre-validate it.